# How to make textInputField's error text accessible(Talkback/VoiceOver) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using inputTextField in Flutter and want to make the error labels accessible.
Is there a direct way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the error label text?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh.. I don't want to change the label text, but when I am using accessibility mode like Talkback on android it should read out what the label is.

Answer (score 0):

First step enable TalkBack (Android reader) and VoiceOver (iOS reader).
Second Step use Semantics Widget

Comment: @ akram abdullah..I have already added Semantics, it however doesn't call out the error field on the textInputField

Answer (score 0):

To enable the Accessibility tool to read the error text bound to a certain TextField, you have to assign a ***FormGlobalKey*** to your Textfield and a ***validator*** function to perform the validation (to identify the error state). Both elements are available in the *TextFormField* class

```
TextFormField(
  ...
  key: FormFieldKey() // your key
  validator: (value){
    // validate here, and return a String that will be your error text
  }
  ...
)
```

One you have linked your key to your textfield, if you call

```
key?.currentState?.validate()
```

and the validation results in error, your accessibility tool should read the error when tapping on the textfield.